# Is it possible to compare two trees with recursion schemes?

Tags: haskell, tree, abstract-syntax-tree, catamorphism, recursion-schemes

I have this AST

```
data ExprF r = Const Int | Add   r r
type Expr = Fix ExprF
```

and I want to compare

```
x = Fix $ Add (Fix (Const 1)) (Fix (Const 1))
y = Fix $ Add (Fix (Const 1)) (Fix (Const 2))
```

But all recursion schemes functions seems to work only with single structure

Obviously I can use recursion

```
eq (Fix (Const x)) (Fix (Const y)) = x == y
eq (Fix (Add x1 y1)) (Fix (Add x2 y2)) = (eq x1 x2) && (eq y1 y2)
eq _ _ = False
```

But I hope it is possible to use some sort of zipfold function.

Comment: From where are you getting your Fix?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes

Comment: You probably want a zygohistomorphic prepromorphism. I have no idea what it does, but with a name like that, I can't imagine there is much it *can't* do. :)

Comment: In recursion-schemes Fix has instance for Eq1

Answer (score 6):

Recursion schemes that act on a single argument are enough, because we can return a function from a scheme application. In this case, we can return an `Expr -> Bool` function from a scheme application on `Expr`. For efficient equality checking we only need paramorphisms:

```
{-# language DeriveFunctor, LambdaCase #-}

newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
data ExprF r = Const Int | Add r r deriving (Functor, Show)
type Expr = Fix ExprF

cata :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata f = go where go (Fix ff) = f (go <$> ff)

para :: Functor f => (f (Fix f, a) -> a) -> Fix f -> a
para f (Fix ff) = f ((\x -> (x, para f x)) <$> ff)

eqExpr :: Expr -> Expr -> Bool
eqExpr = cata $ \case
  Const i -> cata $ \case
    Const i' -> i == i'
    _        -> False
  Add a b -> para $ \case
    Add a' b' -> a (fst a') && b (fst b')
    _         -> False
```

Of course, `cata` is trivially implementable in terms of `para`:

```
cata' :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata' f = para (\ffa -> f (snd <$> ffa)
```

Technically, almost all useful functions are implementable using `cata`, but they aren't necessarily efficient. We can implement `para` using `cata`:

```
para' :: Functor f => (f (Fix f, a) -> a) -> Fix f -> a
para' f = snd . cata (\ffa -> (Fix (fst <$> ffa) , f ffa))
```

However, if we use `para'` in `eqExpr` we get quadratic complexity, since `para'` is always linear in the size of the input, while we can use `para` to peek at the topmost `Expr` values in constant time.

Comment: Is it possible to write a polymorphic version of `eqExpr` like `cataZipWith :: Fix f -> Fix f -> (f a -> f c -> a) -> a` ?

Comment: @András Kovács In the implementation of `eqExpr`, why are the catas/paras behind the pattern-matches necessary? Couldn't we pattern match directly on the second tree?

Comment: @danidiaz I took it that we can use only recursion schemes.

Comment: @danidiaz that's also against the spirit of [bananas and lenses](http://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

(This response uses the **data-fix** library because I couldn't get **recursion-schemes** to compile.)

We can model the diff of two trees as an anamorphism or unfolding of a "diff functor" that is based on the original functor.

Consider the following types

```
data DiffF func r = Diff (Fix func) (Fix func) 
                  | Nodiff (func r)
                  deriving (Functor)

type ExprDiff = Fix (DiffF ExprF)
```

The idea is that `ExprDiff` will follow the "common structure" of the original `Expr` trees as long as it remains equal, but at the moment a difference is encountered, we switch to the `Diff` leaf, that stores the two subtrees that we found to be different.

The actual comparison function would be:

```
diffExpr ::  Expr -> Expr -> ExprDiff  
diffExpr e1 e2 = ana comparison (e1,e2)
    where
    comparison :: (Expr,Expr) -> DiffF ExprF (Expr,Expr)
    comparison (Fix (Const i),Fix (Const i')) | i == i' = 
        Nodiff (Const i')
    comparison (Fix (Add a1 a2),Fix (Add a1' a2')) = 
        Nodiff (Add (a1,a1') (a2,a2'))
    comparison (something, otherthing) = 
        Diff something otherthing
```

The "seed" of the anamorphism is the pair of expressions we want to compare.

If we simply want a predicate `Expr -> Expr -> Bool` we can later use a catamorphism that detects the presence of `Diff` branches.